# 'ChromiumWebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'NewScreenshot'

Tags: cefsharp

I'm just looking into CefSharp and am confused about NewScreenshot. I've found lots of references to it as well as example code, but none of it works. I found it marked as obsolete in the 63.0 docs...

Has NewScreenshot been removed? If so, what replaces it (how can I tell that the screen has rendered)? For my purposes a blocking (non-async) method would work fine.

**Update**:

Searching the source for the latest version of CefSharp I find no reference to NewScreenshot.

I started with the Minimal Example that @amaitland referred to. I made a few changes, adapting it for my use. As part of that change I moved the Shutdown() call to the program's destructor.

When I ran the project I received a mystifying error about calling Shutdown() from a thread different than the thread from which Initialize() was called.

Looking through the code I saw ScreenshotAsync and, as I wasn't (knowingly) using another thread, suspected it may be involved. I looked for another way to get my SVG image and found NewScreenshot. Which of course didn't solve my problem, which was that the **GC** was running my destructor in a different thread (I had no idea that could happen).

At any rate, by this time I'd shucked ScreenshotAsync for NewScreenshot which is how I ended up here.

I set a breakpoint in my handler (which I haven't included as it's never called). Here's what I hope is the relevant code. I've omitted the init code but I believe it's unchanged from the example.

```
public static void Main()
{
   private const string url = "https://www.google.com/";

   browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

   browser.Paint += OnBrowserPaint;

   browser.Load(url)

   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

In stepping through the code in the debugger, I set a breakpoint on browser.Load(url). If I examine browser.Paint, I find errors:

[image]

Here's the tooltip for DeclaringMethod:

[image]

I have no idea if this is related to my event handler not firing, but want to point it out in the event it is involved.

I appreciate your other suggestions but feel I need to find out why an event that should be firing is not.

I'll be happy to reduce and upload the project if it will help. Oh, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Each release has a branch, so you can easily look at the source for whichever branch interests you. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#release-branches You can use the paint event http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/E_CefSharp_OffScreen_ChromiumWebBrowser_Paint.htm

Comment: @amaitland Thanks - it looks like NewScreenshot's gone - I can't find it in the source.

Compared to NewScreenshot, PaintEvent is difficult to use. All I need is a Bitmap which is exactly what NewScreenshot provided. Any alternatives to dealing with an IntPtr?

Comment: The Paint event is only trivially harder to use, there is still a ScreenshotOrNull method to generate the bitmap. Dig through the source a bit more, look at the ScreenshotAsync method for some further clues.

Comment: @amaitland My concern was working with Unsafe code (IntPtr), but I found a way around that. I've got my Paint event coded but it doesn't fire. I'm looking into that now. Pointing the browser.Paint property to my handler is all I've done - I don't have to enable it do I? I didn't have to do anything special to get my LoadingStateChanged handler to fire.

Comment: @amaitland, I broke at the line after I added my handler to browser.Paint. Examining the browser object in the watch window, I see errors in browser.Paint.Method.DeclaringType.DeclaringMethod and elsewhere. They all seem to revolve around generic types. Is this normal?

Comment: `CefSharp` is built with `GitLink`, you can step into the code, see https://github.com/GitTools/GitLink#gitlink

`browser.ScreenshotAsync(ignoreExistingScreenshot:true)` works, so the `Paint` event must be firing correctly.

Comment: You should update your question with the code that you've tried.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing purposes

Comment: @amaitland, I've updated the issue.

Comment: The errors you are seeing in the debugger are safe to ignore. Pass the `Url` into the `ChromiumWebBrowser` constructor. If that doesn't work then please fork the `MinimalExample` push your changes to `GitHub`.

Comment: @amaitland, My event handler is called when I pass the URL to the constructor. So now my question becomes: Why does the event not fire in response to the Load() call?

Comment: @amaitland, It appears that the Paint event is called multiple times for a single web page. Is there a way to tell when it's being called with the final rendered image? If not I'll try switching back to the async screenshot event.

Comment: @amaitland, I switched back to the async screenshot handler. I didn't wait long enough for the browser to initialize and got an excellent diagnostic pointing this out and recommending I use IsBrowserInitializedChanged to detect initialization. But VS doesn't recognize IsBrowserInitializedChanged. I see lots of references to it in the CefSharp master folder. Suggestions?

Comment: @amaitland Using Sleep() to avoid the IsBrowserInitializedChanged issue and your ScreenshotAsync suggestion, I'm able to capture snapshots of web pages, but nothing else. Unfortunately, what I need to do is load local files (preferably SVG, but wrapped in HTML if necessary). Using the CefSharp.WPF.Example as a browser, I can open local SVG by dragging and dropping. The address bar shows "file:///C:/Test/LeatherTag.svg" and the image renders properly. But if I use the same string in the ChromiumWebBrowser constructor, test.Result is a null bitmap.

Comment: @amaitland, I've also tried loading a file into a string and loading that via browser.LoadHtml(). Regardless of whether I try to load an SVG file or an HTML file, task.Result is null. I tried LoadString() but it, like Load(), do not fire the LoadingStateChanged event. I tried LoadHtml() last because I read somewhere that it was not reliable - is that true?

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/E_CefSharp_OffScreen_ChromiumWebBrowser_BrowserInitialized.htm and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#resourcehandler